# How to show a disk is homotopically equivalent to a point?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $D^2 = \{x\in \Bbb R^2: |x|\leq 1\}$ be the $2$-disc. A point can be in any space.

There is a unique $f$ from $D^2$ to the point, but how do we define a map from that point to the disk?

Comment: Let $g$ send the point to $0\in D^2\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Then $f\circ g$ is the identity on the point. While $g\circ f$ is the function that sends all elements of $D^2$ to $0$. Use the homotopy $H(t,x)=tx$ for $(t,x)\in[0,1]\times D^2$ to show that $g\circ f$ is homotopic to the identity.

Comment: A map from a point to a topological space is basically the same thing as an element of (the underlying set of) that topological space.